# android button click not working in  program

Tags: android

Hello everybody i have a problem that when i click a button it remains as it is instead of starting new activity. I searched he problem in this site and found some solutions but none of them worked for me so i am writing my problem here.

the xml layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/profile" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/create_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/create_profile" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/create_profile"
        android:text="@string/edit_profile" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edit_profile"
        android:text="@string/delete_profile" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/delete_profile"
        android:text="@string/activate" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/create_profile"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/create_profile"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/no_profiles" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the activity is

```
package com.android.SmartSwitch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Profile_Manager extends Activity {
    private Button createButton;
    private Button editButton;
    private Button deleteButton;
    private Button activateButton;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);
        setUpViews();
    }



    private void setUpViews() {
        createButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create_profile);
        editButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
        deleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete_profile);
        activateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.activate);

        createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Profile_Manager.this, Add_Profile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        activateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.SmartSwitch"

    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SmartSwitchActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Location_Manager" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity android:name=".Profile_Manager" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity android:name=".Schedule_Manager" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity android:name=".Location_In_Map" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity android:name=".Add_Profile" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

When i click createButton, it doesn't respond

Comment: could you attach your manifest file too

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the problem here. you need to use debugger unless someone else helps. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html

Comment: hmm try adding logs in the click listener to see of the button is getting its click event. And i also noticed ur package name com.android.SmartSwitch. U shouldn't use that, as it is used by android. And it can create conflicts if they have the same files.

Comment: Finally i solved the problem but don't know how this worked. I changed the order of Views in xml file. Now the button starts responding. I moved ListView and TextView from bottom of the file to top and amazingly it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your Main Activity i.e., **Profile_Manager** consists of the following Code:

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SmartSwitchActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You have to note if the Profile Manager class is the class which will be launched i.e., if Profile_Manager Class is the First Screen then, you should create the above code in AndroidManifest.xml with the only change as android:name=".Profile_Manager" instead of "SmartSwitchActivity" with the code additionally added for Add_Profile class as follows

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Add_Profile" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I suppose by doing this changes,things will work fine.

If you are not able to understand the above working then,Here is the Link with Perfect Working Example and with available **Source Code-**[Correct Working of Button Click](http://android.programmerguru.com/android-intent-example/)